# Can switch case in c++ be used to sum the outcomes of many selections

Tags: c++, switch-statement, inorder

I am running a Genetic Programming using c++, we found solution depending on how some gates are placed in series, these gates are selected from constant list of gate library within my program. A switch was called inside an inorder function to print out those gates used to get the solution. What i want now is to assign cost to each of the gate and print their SUM as the gates are printed out previously. can i still use switch case for this? this is example

```
switch1 (gateLibrary)
{
case -1:cout<<"*";break;
case  0:cout<<"a";break;
case  1:cout<<"b";break;
case  2:cout<<"c";break;
             .
             .
             .
case  n:cout<<"z";break;
}
example output: a*b*c
```

This code print the gates selected from gateLibrary stack. for example a*b*c if a,b and c are executed in their cases. Now if a has a cost of 5, b has a cost of 3 and c has a cost of 2 and i want to use another switch to print the total cost as 10 is it possible? I tried something like this for the exact above solution.

```
switch2 (gateLibrary)
{
case -1:cout<<"+";break;
case  0:cout<<"5";break;
case  1:cout<<"3";break;
case  2:cout<<"2";break;
             .
             .
             .
case  n:cout<<"n";break;
}
example output: 5+3+2 //but i need sum as 10 to be printed here
```

any help will be appreciated using anything appropriate not necessarily a switch. Thanks

Comment: Are we to understand that in your examples, you have your code in some sort of `while` loop or other construct that is passing first `gateLibrary=0`, then `gateLibrary=1`, etc.?

Comment: Table Lookup or lookup table.  You can create a *mapping* table to map integers to letters (simple array) or you can do something more complex like using `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an expression parser in the c++ library so you can't take the string"5+3+2" or whatever and end up with 10 without parsing the string yourself. I think you also misunderstand that case labels can have arbitrary values, so you can just make each label have the "cost" you want for each "gate".